# Error Passing Price To Paypal

Tags: c#, paypal

I keep getting an error of the below anytime I try to pass my prices over to paypal.  What should I do to fix this?

> An Exception of type System.FormatException occured in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

```
protected void MakePPLPayment(string itemInfo, string qty)
{
    redirecturl += "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["paypalemail"].ToString();
    redirecturl += "&first_name=" + Session["name"];
    redirecturl += "&city=" + Session["city"];
    redirecturl += "&state=" + Session["state"];
    var itemInfos = itemInfo.Split('|');
    var qtys = qty.Split('|');
    var amounts = amount.Split('|');
    for (int i = 0; i < itemInfos.Count(); i++)
    {
        if (itemInfos[i] != "" && qtys[i] != "" && qtys[i] != "0")
        {
            redirecturl += "&item_name_" + (i + 1) + "=" + itemInfos[i];
            redirecturl += "&quantity_" + (i + 1) + "=" + qtys[i];
            redirecturl += "&amount_" + (i + 1) + "=" + Math.Round(CalculateThis(amounts[i]), 2);
            redirecturl += "&tax_" + (i + 1) + "=" + Math.Round(CalculateThis(amounts[i]) * Convert.ToDecimal(0.07), 2);
        }
    }
    redirecturl += "&night_phone_a=" + Session["phone"];
    redirecturl += "&address1=" + Session["email"];
     redirecturl += "&business=er321224@hotmail.com";
    redirecturl += "&shipping=0";
    redirecturl += "&handling=0";
    redirecturl += "&tax=" + tax;
    redirecturl += "&currency=" + Session["currency"];;
    redirecturl += "&return=" +
      ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SuccessURL"].ToString();
    redirecturl += "&cancel_return=" +
      ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FailedURL"].ToString();
    Response.Redirect(redirecturl);
}
private decimal CalculateThis(object p)
{
    if (p == null)
        return 0;
    else if (p == "")
        return 0;
    return Convert.ToInt16(p);
}
```

The error is thrown on this line `return Convert.ToInt16(p);` and the value of `p` is `9.7000` when the error is thrown.

**EDIT**
This is syntax that shows how string value is achieved, maybe this will help out to remedy my issue:

```
protected void PPLSelected_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var qtys = CalculateThis(dropdowncount.SelectedItem.Text) + "|" + CalculateThis(dropdowncount1.SelectedItem.Text) + "|" + CalculateThis(dropdowncount2.SelectedItem.Text) + "|" + CalculateThis(dropdowncount3.SelectedItem.Text) + "|" + CalculateThis(dropdowncount4.SelectedItem.Text) + "|" + CalculateThis(dropdowncount5.SelectedItem.Text) + "|" + CalculateThis(dropdowncount6.SelectedItem.Text);
    var items = dropdownitem.SelectedItem.Text + "|" + dropdownitem1.SelectedItem.Text + "|" + dropdownitem2.SelectedItem.Text + "|" + dropdownitem3.SelectedItem.Text + "|" + dropdownitem4.SelectedItem.Text + "|" + dropdownitem5.SelectedItem.Text + "|" + dropdownitem6.SelectedItem.Text;
    var amounts = dropdownamt.SelectedItem.CalculateThisue + "|" + dropdownamt1.SelectedItem.CalculateThisue + "|" + dropdownamt2.SelectedItem.CalculateThisue + "|" + dropdownamt3.SelectedItem.CalculateThisue + "|" + dropdownamt4.SelectedItem.CalculateThisue + "|" + dropdownamt5.SelectedItem.CalculateThisue + "|" + dropdownamt6.SelectedItem.CalculateThisue;
    MakePPLPayment(items, qtys);
}
```

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: @SonerGönül - I am not setting it in the syntax, where would I do such?

Comment: Just check your `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` property.

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.ToInt16(object)` method uses [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx) *by default*.

I think your `CurrentCulture`'s [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx) is not `.` but [`NumberGroupSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator.aspx) is `.`, that's why this method thinks this is `97000`, not `9.7`.

You can supply a culture that has `.` as a `NumberDecimalSeparator` like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx).

```
return Convert.ToInt16(p, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

As a full code;

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     object o = 9.7000;
     CalculateThis(o);
}

public static decimal CalculateThis(object p)
{
     if (p == null)
         return 0;
     else if (p == "")
         return 0;
     return Convert.ToInt16(p, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FF0BYM)</kbd>.

Comment: This throws a compile error of 'string' does not contain a definition for 'InvariantCulture'

Comment: @RashidAbib What? o.O Which string exactly? That shouldn't give any compiler error if you write it properly.

Comment: When you add CultureInfo you receive System.FormatException.

Comment: @Mariusz No, if you add `InvariantCulture`, it will definitely **not**.

Comment: @RashidAbib This edit clarifies nothing. This isn't the same code on above. It is a totally different method.

Comment: @Mariusz - so sorry, I copied pasted the wrong methods, this is the one I meant to paste showing how the info was passed to MakePPLPayment

Answer (score 0):

In your case better method to do that is `int.TryParse()`.

Example:

```
int example = 0;
int.TryParse("9.7000", out example);
```

Comment: This gives me a compile error of No overload method for 'TryParse' takes 1 argument.  I used return int.TryParse(p);

Comment: Use documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf50za27(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: _Convert.ToInt16() works only for int numbers_ That's quite wrong. It has so many overloads that takes `object`, `string`, `long`, `float` as a parameter. And using `int` for parsing is not _have to_. `Int16` can parse this as well. Only matter is culture settings.